# Submitting data with python mechanize

Tags: python, forms, submit, mechanize, mechanize-python

Im trying to submit a form by submitting to this submit button

```
<div class="input-btn">
        <a class="iconized post-clear" href="" ng-show="!postdata.data.$error.required" ng-click="clearData()" title="Clear Field"><i class="icon-x"


        ></i></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium post-send"
            ng-class="{'disabled' : postdata.userData.$error.required}"
            ng-disabled="postdata.userData.$error.required"
            ng-click="postData(7922736, model.userData)" ng-cloak>
            Submit            </button>
    </div>
```

with the code

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form("postData")
br.set_all_readonly(False)
br["data"] = data
br.submit()
```

The form is filled in correctly with my data, but nothing gets submitted

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
r = br.submit()
print r.read()
```

From my understanding of `br.submit()`, it is actually submitting the form as you want, but you'd need a way to get the returned result. Hence, assign a new variable, `r` to `br.submit()`, and retrieve what the submit does by reading the new page, hence, `r.read()`.

Hope this helps

Comment: @DavidBowling I added a short explanation. Thx for the suggestion.